# Pycrypto : AES Decryption

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto

Why Pycrypto AES decryption gives different output when decrypted with AES object used for encryption and right output when decrypted with AES object used solely for decryption?

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
obj = AES.new('0123456789012345', AES.MODE_CBC, '0123456789012345')
message = '0123456789012345'
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
plaintext = obj.decrypt(ciphertext)
# plaintext here is byte array
obj2 = AES.new('0123456789012345', AES.MODE_CBC, '0123456789012345')
plaintext = obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
# plaintext here is 0123456789012345
```

Comment: Is the state of `obj` reset after the call to `encrypt`? Otherwise the IV would be different...

Comment: How to check the state of obj and what difference it makes, as i am not able to see the source code used for encrypt and decrypt functions in the library.

Comment: Maybe it's in the documentation? I currently don't have access to it...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I think that's exactly it. I see no other possible explanation. The answer probably lies in the source code of libtomcrypt as well as the Python wrapper that is called pycrypto.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I do have access to the documentation at home, seems I guessed right, added answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`BlockAlgo#encrypt`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.blockalgo.BlockAlgo-class.html#encrypt) from which the AES class is derived:

> Encrypt data with the key and the parameters set at initialization.
>
> The cipher object is **stateful**; encryption of a long block of data can be broken up in two or more calls to encrypt(). That is, the statement:
>
> ```
> c.encrypt(a) + c.encrypt(b)
> ```
>
> is always equivalent to:
>
> ```
> c.encrypt(a+b)
> ```
>
> **That also means that you cannot reuse an object for encrypting or decrypting other data with the same key.**

So your problem is actually directly documented in the class.

Comment: I don't understand the logic in this. Consider the class `MyClass` with the methods `double(self, number)` and `half(self, number)`, which double the number and half the number respectively. `half` is the inverse of `double`, so you could think of it as encryption/decryption. `cipher = MyClass()`; `cipher.half(cipher.double(3))` does return `3`

Comment: The operations double and half don't have any state of their own. Check [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)), it propagates the ciphertext to be used to parameterize the encryption / decryption of the next block. The first block is parameterized with the IV.

Comment: Still, they are the same class with the same attributes and methods, just different instance names.