# Encrypting-Decrypting multiple times

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto

I'm trying my hand at Cryptography using Python2.7. I'm able to encrypt-decrypt a text once. But when I try to encrypt-decrypt multiple times, in a loop, it doesn't give back the original string in variable p. Please have a look at my code, and suggest what can be done. Thanks!

```
import os, random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

'''Encryption'''

k = 'mykey'
hasher = SHA256.new(k)
k = hasher.digest()

p = 'enigmaticaura'
print p
IV = ''

lp = len(p)

for i in range(16):
    IV += chr(random.randint(0,0xFF))

if len(p)%16 != 0:
    p += ' '*(16 - len(p)%16)

enc = AES.new(k, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
for i in range(2):
    p = enc.encrypt(p)
    print p

'''Decryption'''

dec = AES.new(k, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
for i in range(2):
    p = dec.decrypt(p)

#p = p[:lp]
    print p
```

Comment: So, what's the problem with the result?

Comment: Your problem description is not helpful. What exactly are you expecting? What exactly are you getting?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not able to get the original string p (='enigmaticaura') after decryption. Have also edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Please use the checkmark next to the answer to say the question is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer first: Python isn't exactly my strong point but hey, it's been a while since I answered anything so why not...

I guess your question should have been something like "why doesn't the decryption produce the original input".

For one thing - why? Using the same key isn't really going to make the encryption any better.

And for two - it's not meant to work like that. I'm pretty sure it is to do with the fact that the encrypt and decrypt objects are stateful and cannot be reused. [This SO post describes it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43218302) in more detail.

But, two small changes will make it (sort of) work, in as much as you'll get the original source back.

```
for i in range(2):
    enc = AES.new(k, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)   ## move this line inside the loop
    p = enc.encrypt(p)
    print p
```

and

```
for i in range(2):
    dec = AES.new(k, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)   ## and this line too
    p = dec.decrypt(p)
```

which may, or may not be what you were hoping for.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! :)
Although, I'm not really sure why it worked. The enc/dec variable was not altered, so redefining them again for the next iteration doesn't make sense. 
I guess using the .encrypt/.decrypt method was perhaps the reason.

Comment: @harsh-kolhatkar That's the point - the enc/dec variables *are* altered, internally. They maintain internal state and can't be reused.  By recreating them you are, in effect, resetting them.